# When I return to the previous page MediaPlayer continues playing

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried all these and still the media player continues playing when I press the back button and return to the previous activity

```
oncreate ........ new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int newInt = sharedPreferences.getInt("B" , DEFALT );
            if (newInt == DEFALT) {
                releaseMediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(AlsamadSuraST3.this, wordsResourceArray[0][0]);
                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
                    editor.putInt("B" , DEFALT + 5 );
                    editor.apply();;
                }
            }

   @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    releaseMediaPlayer();

    }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    releaseMediaPlayer();

}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {

    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;

        mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(mOnAudioFocusChangeListener);
    }
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    releaseMediaPlayer();
}
```

How can I stop the media player when i return to the previous activity >> there are many answers included onpause , onstop ondestroy  but none of them worked

Comment: has you tried onResume()?

Comment: I will now ....

Comment: it didn't work ...

Comment: try to make mediaPlayer singleton, or make it static if they is easier.

Comment: what it could change the situation ?

Comment: anyway it worked (static)  thanx ... it worked but i dont know why it worked now and not before

Comment: without being singleton or static, there could be multiple instances of mediaPlayer, and the one you stop may not be the one that actually playing.